# How to install/use MoneroPHP on my site?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod

I have the site [xmrto.cash](https://xmrto.cash) and just want to accept and send XMR. I was told MoneroPHP is a good way to do this but am having trouble just understanding how to install and use it.

What is the first step to installing this on my site?

Answer (score 2):

> How to install/use MoneroPHP on my site?

The [README](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp) details how to use the library (which is itself well [documented](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/tree/master/docs)).

> What is the first step to installing this on my site?

The first step is to install and run the Monero daemon and wallet RPC applications.

Note, you really don't *need* to use the library; it largely just wraps the daemon and wallet JSON RPC interfaces. So if you are comfortable making web requests directly in PHP, no wrapper library is needed.